# What is cpp compiler path for mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I want to specify the compilerPath in the VScode for compiling the C++, but I don't know what should be the correct path

OS: macOS BigSur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this firstly, I checked the that is g++(compiler for C++) is installed in my mac or not.
For doing this I goes to `/usr/bin`
Then i specify the path in `compilerPath` as `/usr/bin/g++`